# dict.update() not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, increment

I have an empty dictionary, which I am manipulating with the update method. I am using a variable as the key and `+1` as the value. See below:

```
myDict, var = {}, 10
myDict.update( { var : +1 } )
```

Let's say I execute this twice, I expect `myDict = {10 : 2}`. Instead, it is `{10 : 1}`.

I understand I can directly resolve this issue by doing this:

```
myDict[var] += 1
print (myDict)
{10 : 2}
```

However, `var` is not always `10` I would like to increment, `var` can be any number. If it was any number other than `10`, I would get a `KeyError` as the key does not exist in the dictionary.

How can I update the dictionary with a variable as the key, and set the value as `1`, but if the key already exists in `myDict`, then to increment the respective value instead?

I have already done this through a try and except statement but I feel it is not very Pythonic.

```
try:
    myDict[var] += 1
except:
    myDict.update( { var : 1 } )
```

This way, it will try to increment `var`'s value by one. If the key doesn't exist, then `myDict` will be updated instead to create the key and set the value as one. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for a Counter; Python offers this for you in the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
var = 10    
c.update({var: 1})
print(c) # Counter({10: 1})
c.update({var: 1})
print(c) # Counter({10: 2})
```

You can get the same result with a plain dict by using `d[var] = d.get(var, 0) + 1` if you'd like but, the `Counter` option is, in my opinion, clearer in this case.

Comment: This works very well. Is it possible to add counters to a Pandas dataframe? As I would like to do this at the end of my program.

Comment: Dataframes can take a dictionary as input so I'd be surprised if it didn't accept Counters for some reason. If it doesn't you can always use `dict(c)` when passing it.

Comment: @AugustWilliams You'll just have to pass an index if your counts are scalars as they appear to be, e.g. `pd.DataFrame(Counter([4, 5, 2, 4, 5]), index=[0])`

Comment: Just tried adding to a dataframe as if they were dictionaries - works perfectly fine.